# "play is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: playframework

I am new to play framework. I added the path of the play folder in my environment variable - C:\play-2.1.2\play .
On console, when i go inside the play folder and run "play" command, it works but when i created a new application and ran play inside it, it showed me an error - "play is not recognized as an internal or external command" . Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Changing it to `C:\play-2.1.2\` should work (remove the last `play` thing). Also be sure to add this to environment variable `Path`, not somewhere else

Comment: That didn't work for me. Is there another solution?